# "Could not find generator oauth_consumer" running "rails generate oauth_consumer"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, generator, oauth-2.0

I'm getting "Could not find generator oauth_consumer" running "rails generate oauth_consumer"???

Ok so I'm new to Rails 3 (just getting back into it).   Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to follow the following however I'm guessing things have changed with Rails 3...

http://xaop.com/blog/2010/03/05/authentication-with-oauth-in-ruby-on-rails/

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:googleweekends greg$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

Gregs-MacBook-Pro:googleweekends greg$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.1
```

Have added this to the Gemfile:

```
    gem 'oauth'
    gem 'oauth-plugin'
```

Have run "bundle install" - not sure if it was required given I'd separately done "gem install" for the oauth gem and plugin.

Gregs-MacBook-Pro:googleweekends greg$ bundle install

```
...<cut>...
Using oauth (0.4.5)
Using oauth-plugin (0.3.14)
Using rails (3.2.1)
...<cut>...
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Error:

```
Gregs-MacBook-Pro:googleweekends greg$ rails generate oauth_consumer
Could not find generator oauth_consumer.
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - justed notice a gem plugin version dependency - when I added this to my GemFile it worked....

```
gem "oauth-plugin", ">= 0.4.0.pre1"
```

taken from:

https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin